# I have a list stored in resultlist as follows:

Tags: c#

```
var resultlist = results.ToList();
```

**It looks something like this**I want to clear firstname and lastname of all index with only ID Left

```
ID FirstName  LastName
-- ---------  --------
1  Bill       Smith
2  John       Wilson
3  Doug       Berg
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take a moment to follow the tour. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultlist = results.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

This will result in a list of integers, e.g. your IDs.

I do want to address the title of your question. Try to formulate your title so anyone reading it understands what you're asking. Example: 'How do I get a list of Ids from my list of objects?'

**Update:**

This will result in a list with your Ids and empty first- and lastnames

```
var resultlist = results.Select(x => { x.FirstName = ""; x.LastName = ""; return x;}).ToList();
```

Comment: _clear_ could also mean that the fields `FirstName` and `LastName` should remain empty

Comment: @fubo true, this isn't clear from the question. I don't see the purpose of having empty strings in any situation though, hence you only select the Ids

Comment: i want to make changes in list itself because i have to add new values in that place after clearing it.

Comment: Another way would be a simple for loop `for (int i = 0; i < resultlist.Count; i++) { resultlist[i].FirstName = ""; resultlist[i].LastName = ""; }`